# Loop over the names of files and apply a function on them in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, directory

I have folder containing thousands of (*.jpg) images inside and would like to loop over the name of them  and apply calculations on them.

has anybody kind of loop in mind for this?

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the variables that are determining your filenames and use sprintf() to format those variables into strings.

I can't quite figure out your filename pattern, but you would read the first group like this, for example:

```
for i = 0:9

    % The %d character will be replaced by i in the string
    filename = sprintf('abcda0b%d99.jpg',i);
    im = imread(filename);

    % Image calculations

end
```

If your filenames obey a single pattern, you can do this with nested loops to construct the filename from the variables that are determining your filename. If you reply with more detail about your naming pattern I can help you out.

Comment: yes , sure. The names patterns are like the following : abcd_a0b0.jpg, abcd_a0b99.jpg, abcd_a0b199.jpg, ...abcd_a0b9899.jpg,abcd_a0b9999.jpg, abcd_a0b1009.jpg, ...abcd_a0b1289.jpg.

Comment: yes , sure. The names patterns are like the following : abcd_a0b0.jpg, abcd_a0b99.jpg, abcd_a0b199.jpg, ...abcd_a0b9899.jpg,abcd_a0b9999.jpg, abcd_a0b1009.jpg, ...abcd_a0b1289.jpg. Then the new naming starts as followed: abcd_a99b0.jpg, abcd_a99b99.jpg, abcd_a99b199.jpg, ...abcd_a99b12799.jpg. Then the new naming set abcd_a199b0.jpg , abcd_a99b199.jpg, abcd_a99b299.jpg, ... and the last on comes to  abcd_a18399b12799.jpg. The names are assigned during the scanning of  image and the name are coordinates of every scanned point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dir` function:

```
path='The_path_to_directory_contains_the_jpg_files';
d=dir(path);

for k=3:length(d)
    im=imread(fullfile(path,d(k).name));
    % do calculations
end
```